# Using jQuery at Console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, read-eval-print-loop

I'm learning more about jQuery and would like to use it interactively at the JavaScript console in Chrome. Is that possible? I envision something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
> use('jquery.js')
jquery loaded
> $("span").html("Hello World!")
```

This would cause `"Hello World!"` to be inserted between the span tags and displayed.

Comment: Use Opera, there you can load it with `// jquery()` :-)

Answer (score 18):

There is no "use" so of course it will not work.

You can append it to a page.

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

Comment: You may need to use protocol 'https' instead of 'http' of jquery lib file

Comment: Using http, Firefox throws the following error `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js”`

Answer (score 9):

If you have jQuery included in the page that you have the console open on you should be free to use it in the console.

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest way to do this, is to edit the header of the page and add a `<script>` tag pointing to [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js).
Then you will be able to execute the code in your console.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Figured it out :-) I created a simple HTML file that loaded jQuery and then went into the console. This works for me.

Comment: see comment from Wryte, it states the same

Comment: Ok, that's an obvious and simple solution of course. I had expected that you don't own the page where you opened the console and wanted to use jQuery there.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/pen/

You can still access the scripts you create via the chrome console and it will be easier to share with others if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery frequently from the console you can easily write a userscript.
First, install Tampermonkey if you are on Chrome and Greasemonkey if you are on Firefox. Write a simple userscript with a use function like this:

```
var scripts = []
function use(libname){
var src;
if(scripts.indexOf(libname)==-1){
switch(libname.toLowerCase()){  
case "jquery":
src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
break;
case "angularjs":
src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js";
break;
}
}else{
console.log("Library already in use.");
return;
}
if(src){
scripts.append(libname);
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = src;
document.body.appendChild(scr);
}else{
console.log("Invalid Library.");
return;
}
}
```